# Netlify deployment not displaying page content

Tags: javascript, netlify

I have simple Javascript project that builds correctly locally, and I get this result

[image: Local build image]

However, when I deploy it on netlify or run `netlify deploy` locally I get the image below from the draft URL

[image: netlify deployment]

In my `netlify.toml` file I have the following configuration

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  publish = "dist"

[dev]
  command = "yarn start"
  targetPort = 3000
  port = 8888
  publish = "dist"
```

What could be the issue leading to that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove the `homepage` key and value from the package.json because React uses this to build for relative paths.

Also I needed to delete `publicPath` key from `webpack.config.js`

After those changes, the build worked and the deployment was successfull